# show percentage by specifying DefaultCellStyle.Format value in datagridviewcolum

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

```
With datagridview.Columns("PricePerUnit")
    .ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
    .DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
End With
```

A datatable is bound to the datagridview and 
in the above code a If I just add row with a value five to the column "PricePerUnit" 
it will be shown as $5.00 in the datagridview column

Similarly I want to show up something like If I just add row with a value five to the column "DiscountPercentage"

it should show as 5.00%

I need a string value to assign to DefaultCellStyle.Format to achieve this.

If I use `DefaultCellStyle.Format="P"` it automatically multiplies that to 100 and so 
for a input of 5 it shows as 500.00% instead of 5.00%

Any ideas?

---

Resolved

dtb Helped me do this  (thanks to him)

`number.ToString("0.00\%")` gets the decimal number along with 2 decimal integers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you need a [Custom Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) here.

In C#:

```
12m.ToString("0\\%");  // returns "12%"
```

So this should do the trick:

```
pricePerUnitColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0\\%";
```

Comment: trust me you are nothing short of a genius it worked well 
and I used  for also showing 2 decimals after that like  this Number.ToString("0.00\%")

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the value .05 instead of 5? Or is that not an option?

Comment: datagrid view is used for display only, database is updated only from the values from datatable