# Concat decimal value with string

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

I am retrieving data from the database and displaying in Gridview. I have some data in which I want to display % sign at the end (in gridview) what would be the best way to achieve this. Can I concat % sign in sql select statement or I have to add using vb code behind.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show percentage by specifying DefaultCellStyle.Format value in datagridviewcolum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732311/show-percentage-by-specifying-defaultcellstyle-format-value-in-datagridviewcolum)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I loop through the Gridview row and concat % sing at the end

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            If e.Row.Cells(6).Text = 4 Then
                e.Row.Cells(5).Text += " %"
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to **use DataFormatString property from the Gridview columns** and set it to something like "{0:0.00}%". This will format your results by using the number, 2 decimal positions and adding the % symbol to the end.

If you have rows with numeric values and rows that already contain % or other special characters, the best way to assure that the data is correctly visualized would be to remove the % or special characters before setting the Gridview data source. This way you will allways get the same result for each row.

Comment: I have some data in percentage while some are in decimal format. I don't think so this will work

Comment: In this case I would homogenize the column contents by removing the % and special characters of the rows that are not numeric and then apply the format on the gridview. This way you get the same results for all the rows.

Comment: @AmitPatel do you mean the database may have 0.42 and 42, each meaning 42%?

Comment: Actually in select command, I multiply 0.42 value with 100 and trying to get the value.